# Bootstrap layout broke after adding JQuery to my document

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I changed a working document by adding a lot of JQuery functionality to it. In the process, and I didn't realize this until I'd made all the changes, my dropdown menus no longer work on this document. I thought maybe I'd messed up something between the `<head>` tags, so I copy/pasted from another document the Bootstrap and JQuery files. But I still don't have my dropdown menus on the Navbar.

Here is what I have on this document and the other 47 that use Bootstrap:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>        

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Does anyone know of anything like this happening and how to fix it? Please advise.

Comment: Impossible to say with the information provided. Anything in the JS console? Roll back to an earlier version and start adding functionality until it breaks agaibn.

Comment: Dave Newton: sorry for the lack of info. In truth, I don't know what else to provide. My hope is that this isn't a first-ever occurrence and someone will have insight into the problem. But I'll likely end up doing what you suggest and go one potato, two potato until I find what broke it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you added something that messes with your bootstrap. When you are working on javascript and css you really are dealing with a global state and sometimes items do not play well together if they use matching class names etc.. I would consider putting something on a fiddle where you can add and take away dependencies until you can see what broke your nav.

Comment: vikingben: Thanks for your input. I'll definitely consider that. I guess it's time to learn how to "fiddle". Never used that.

Comment: @Landslyde Do `git bisect`-potato instead, or with whatever source control you're using. Yet another reason it's good to work in small chunks.

Comment: FWIW, Bootstrap already has it's own "normalize" baked into it's CSS, so I would either remove that stylesheet, or move it ahead of Bootstrap. I would recommend creating either a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) demonstrating the issue you're having.

Comment: Should also move that "browser upgrade" notice into the body; paragraphs are not allowed in the head of an HTML document.

Comment: @Tieson T.: Thank you. Both are removed.

Comment: 1) Do Botstrap and Jquery localy.. not with CDN..
2) If its not necessary don't load `scripts` in head
3) Bootstap already have normalize in the build so maybe thats the problem

Comment: Found it. I left the `exit()` off the end of the JQuery `$_POST` that loaded names into a `select box` when the document loaded. That's what getting in a hurry gets me! Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Libor Zahrádka - I'll give loading Bootstrap and JQuery locally a shot.